# Deploying a release to a person from a release pipeline in Azure DevOps services

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created a release pipeline with the UI (classic, I guess) in Azure DevOps Services, that consumes build pipeline artifacts from several different build pipelines. I do not have a repo.
In the release pipeline the artifacts are merged and then the final result is put in a zip file. This zip is the release.

The next step is to deploy the release to a team. Before I had the release pipeline, this deployment was done by sending an email with the zip attached.
But now a release pipeline is needed, because the build pipeline artifacts are scattered across many build pipelines, to still keep this process automated.

The team that should get this deployment are not developers (do not have access to DevOps Services).
It seems like deploying to a person using email is not possible. So, somehow I have to get hold of the physical zip file and put it where they can access it. Now I can only see in the logs that it was created.
One idea I have is to put the zip in SharePoint, then I could start a Power Automate flow to send an email with a link to the zip. But I do not know if I can deploy to SharePoint from the release pipeline.

But surely there must be a simpler way to deploy a release to a person, with a release pipeline?

Please give me some good advice on how to proceed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a [send email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask&targetId=e4054f0d-79f1-4feb-bb80-6a31368202cb) task that you can add at the end of your release pipeline. It can be downloaded from the Marketplace

Comment: How can I specifiy the zip file attachment that I would like to send by mail?

Comment: There is an "Add Attachment?" tick box you need to check, you would then need to specify the absolute path to the zip you wish to attach

Comment: Great! Is this task also supported for Azure DevOps Services? It says "Azure DevOps Server" in the dialog where I request the admin to install it.

Comment: On the right hand side of the page there is a "Works With" section. Both service and server are listed

Comment: The Send email task worked very well! I am a bit surprised though, that you have to go to  Marketplace to be able to send a mail with attachment from a release pipeline. It is strange that it is not included by default, especially since so many other options, like Publish Pipeline Artifact, are not available from a release pipeline.